# Invalid Data HttpWebResponse from HttpWebRequest C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-services, rest

I am trying to load an HttpWebResponse into an XmlDocument and am getting the exception "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1".  If I output the response to the Console I get "system.net.connectstream".  The credentials don't seem to be my problem because if I enter an incorrect password my exception changes to the 404 error.  Here is my code...

```
string username = "username";
string password = "password";
string url = "https://myurl.com";

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
Console.WriteLine(response.GetResponseStream());
xmlDoc.Load(response.GetResponseStream());
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `ToString` on `GetResponseStream()` isn't going to do much for you - `Stream.ToString` isn't overridden.

I suggest you use something like this for debugging::

```
// Prefer casting over "as" unless you're going to check it...
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        // For diagnostics, let's assume UTF-8
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Then replace the middle section `(with StreamReader)` with the `XmlDocument.Load` call.

I suspect you'll see that it's basically invalid XML, but the above should show you what it really is.

EDIT: Your comment shows the data as:

```
{"messages":{"message":"1 Device(s) returned."},"devices":{"device":
    {"@id":"00","uuid":"00000000","phonenumber":"000‌​000",
     "user name":"0000","name":"Guy,Somebody","platform":"platform","os":"III",
     "version":"1‌​.1.1"}},"appName":"someApp"}
```

That's JSON. It's not XML. Don't try to load it as XML. You have two options:

- Change what you're requesting so that you get an XML response back, if the server supports it
- Parse it as JSON (e.g. with [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com)) instead of as XML.

Comment: The StreamReader allows me to grab the data and see that I'm getting the proper data, but when I put the XMLDocument.Load back in I get the same error.  Here is what the stream looks like (with data removed)...

Comment: {"messages":{"message":"1 Device(s) returned."},"devices":{"device":{"@id":"00","uuid":"00000000","phonenumber":"000000","user name":"0000","name":"Guy,Somebody","platform":"platform","os":"III","version":"1.1.1"}},"appName":"someApp"}